# GLM documentation

Tags: opengl

I am using the mathematical library GML (http://glm.g-truc.net/) .
I can't find any documentation. for example:
what does this do?

```
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

what do the arguments represent? is it the same as "gluPerspective" (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml)???

Comment: "I can't find any documentation." Over to the left of that page you link to are two things: "GLM Manual" and "GLM API", both of which are _documentation_.

Answer (score 3):

The idea with GLM is to replicate parameters and functions where possible, so yes: `glm::perspective` uses the same arguments as `gluPerspective`.

Comment: why replace them since they are already in OpenGL defined?

Comment: @TrtTrt: Because they were [deprecated in GL 3.0 and removed in 3.1 core](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts) contexts.